# Iterate through Set in order

Tags: delphi, set

Fairly new to Delphi, so forgive me if this is a trivial question.

I have the following:

```
TMsgDlgBtn = (mbYes, mbNo, mbOK, mbCancel, mbAbort, mbRetry, mbIgnore,
    mbAll, mbNoToAll, mbYesToAll, mbHelp, mbClose);
TMsgDlgButtons = set of TMsgDlgBtn;
```

and this loop:

```
//Buttons is of type TMsgDlgButtons and value is [mbRetry, mbCancel]
for B := Low(TMsgDlgBtn) to High(TMsgDlgBtn) do
   if B in Buttons then
     //Do something with the button B
```

It seems like no matter which order `Buttons` is in, it is always processed with `mbCancel` first, then `mbRetry` second. I saw that this is because of the order of `TMsgDlgBtn` so I tried this instead:

```
for B in Buttons do
  //Do something with the button B
```

but it seems to iterate the same way - cancel first, then retry.

Is this because `Buttons` is a set? Is there any way to iterate through `Buttons` such that the order is respected?

Comment: maybe you could try to use `Integer` variable and cast to `TMsgDlgBtn`..

Comment: I would expect `for B in Buttons` to iterate/enumerate in the declaration order of TMsgDlgButtons, because an enumeration has an inherent order. `Buttons` is a set which has no inherent order.  I don't follow why you expect otherwise.

Comment: If order is of importance, don't add buttons to a set, add them to a `TList<TMsgDlgBtn>`. From there it is easy to iterate in the order they are added: `for btn in myList do WriteLn(Ord(btn));`. Add buttons like: `myList.AddRange([mbRetry,mbCancel]);`

Comment: Sets are not ordered. The Delphi set type mimics the mathematical concept of a set, and such sets are not ordered either. In mathematics, {1, 2, 3} = {3, 2, 1} = {1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2}.

Comment: Indeed, if you need order you can use a `TList<TMsgDlgBtn>` -- or a dynamic array: `TArray<TMsgDlgBtn>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to iterate through Buttons such that the order is respected?

No, because the set doesn't hold the information of, in which order the set members were assigned to the set.

Explanation:

First you declare an enumeration type, `TMsgDlgBtn`. As you did not define any specific values, they are given the values 0, 1, 2, 3 ...

Then you declare the set type, `TMsgDlgButtons`. For members of sets, one bit is reserved for each value. So, 12 bits represent the membership of the buttons in the set.

When you assign `Buttons := [mbRetry, mbCancel]` the corresponding bits of those buttons are set in the `Buttons` set. The implementation of the first `for` loop checks the membership from the lowest to the highest bit, so it is natural that the test is performed on `mbCancel` before `mbRetry`. The implementation of the second `for` loop, is likely done in the same order, from lower to higher bits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Confirms what I was thinking - that sets work differently than arrays. Is there an easy way to convert my set into an array?

Comment: Yes, it's easy, but I don't understand why you think you would need to do so. If you must know first handed whether `mbRetry` is in the set, then test it first.

Comment: It's not whether I want to know if it's in the set or not, I would like to treat the set as if it were an array (iterate through the items with a certain order)

Comment: I recommend that you prepare a new question specifically for the iteration through items in a certain order. But please also make it very clear what your use case is, to avoid being misunderstood.

Comment: @derekantrican "*I would like to treat the set as if it were an array (iterate through the items with a certain order)*: - Sets simply do not work that way.  If order is important, you have to use an actual array/list instead